# Rails: when do we must put :: before some classes for rails understand base class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby, I understand that `::ClassName` for calling class at base module. For example, here is my code:

```
module HHT
  module V1
    module OfflineCheckIn
      class PutOfflineCheckInProductsApi < ApplicationApi
        put 'offline' do
          ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
            OfflineCheckIn.create(check_in_param) # exception here
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run, I meet exception:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `create' for
>   HHT::V1::OfflineCheckIn:Module)

As I understand, Rails understand that `OfflineCheckIn` currently inside module `HHT::V1::OfflineCheckIn`, so I must call at base class `::OfflineCheckIn`. Thing that I don't understand is: at another controller, some previous programmer implements same way with me, but he doesn't need to call `::` before model.

So my question is: when we don't need to use `::` before class and rails can understand that is base class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to call class as `::ClassName` if in your hierarchy there's a class/module with the same name, to differentiate between them, for example:

```
class Foo; end

module Bar
  class Foo; end # this is another Foo

  def self.a
    puts ::Foo == Foo
  end
end

module FooBar
  def self.a
    puts ::Foo == Foo
  end
end

Bar.a # => false
FooBar.a # => true
```

Here we have `::Foo` and `::Bar::Foo`, but shorthand `Foo` points to one of them depending on context.

Also it does not matter if the entities are classes or modules, both are just assigned as a value for a constant:

```
module Foo; end

module Bar
  Foo = "a string"

  def self.baz
    puts Foo.class
  end
end

puts Foo.class # => Module
Bar.baz # => String
```

Comment: are there any other cases? My project only one file with class `OfflineCheckIn`. But there is one module named `OfflineCheckIn` inside `offline_check_in` directory. Will this affect rails how understand class ?

Comment: @TrầnKimDự actually it does not matter is the thing is a class or a module, in fact, both are stored as a value for a constant